# Why does this pattern not match

Tags: regex, iis

I am trying to create a url rewrite rule that will block requests that contain a decimal "page" parameter value instead of a int

I feel like this pattern should be matching but pattern testing is indicating else-wise.

Here is the pattern I am using to look for matches to requests that should be denied: `page=\d+\.\d`

Testing out the string `page=23.1` it is says "The input data to test does not match the pattern."

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the issue select regular expression from the "using" dropdown as shown in below image:

[image]

A “wildcard” in computing terms can mean a wildcard character, which is a character that can represent other characters, or it can mean a wildcard character as part of a file path specification.

Regular expressions are an advanced syntax for matching complex patterns. There are many more special characters in regular expressions than in wildcards.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference

Answer (score 0):

You chose to write a wildcard rule, not a Regex rule. That's why.